# Highchart add three zeros in the loop

Tags: php, highcharts

I have use library chart from this page [link](https://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/basic-line). Unfortunately, the data I download is not compatible, for example:

I get from JSON time:

```
time: 1346803200
```

this time is not displayed on the chart. I must add three zeros at the end (look like this: `1346803200000`), then the chart displays correctly. So I have code:

```
for ($i=0; $i < count($chart['Data']) ; $i++) {
    $time = $chart['Data'][$i]['time'];
}
```

I need add to variable `$time` numeric `000` (three zeros at the end). I can not add it this way:

```
$time = $chart['Data'][$i]['time']."000";
```

because variable `$time` change from `int` to `string`. I must have `$time` in `integer` type. Is there any way to add three zeros without changing the variable type inside the loop ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure why you are doing this or if there is a better way, but if type conversion is the only thing that worries you, you can explicitly cast it to `int`:

`$time = (int)($chart['Data'][$i]['time']."000");`

Also, not sure if this is your desired behavior, but just note that your `$time` variable will get overwritten with every iteration of the `for` loop.

And one more thing, you can achieve your desired output without the explicit conversion by just multiplying your result with 1000, like so:

`$time = $chart['Data'][$i]['time'] * 1000;`

This should be a better solution than concatenation when you are working with `int`s

Answer (score 1):

Seriously?

```
$time = $chart['Data'][$i]['time'] * 1000;
```

Answer (score 1):

You con  multiply for 1000

```
 $time = $chart['Data'][$i]['time']*1000;
```